# What's the weapon on Ross's wall?

Tags: friends

I can't find a good picture of it online, but on Ross's apartment in the first few seasons of *Friends* (before he moves into Naked Guy's apartment), there's a wall hanging he has near the door that looks like some kind of spear, possibly asian. I  thought it might be a yari, but it looks to be about 4' total length, with about half of it blade and half of it handle, which doesn't quite look like a yari.

Anyone know what this weapon is?

Comment: Probably some prehistoric weapon since he is a Paleontologist.

Comment: No, it's clearly steel and wood, not stone or bronze.

Comment: I searched quite a bit and cant find an image either. Would be awesome to see a screencap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]
It’s a crescent blade. The one in this picture is a Green Dragon Crescent Blade.

Answer (score 8):

I know I am late, but that is a Chinese weapon. It's hard to tell because I can't see the full length of the handle, but it's definitely either a horse cutter or a kwan dao. I have actually practiced with both. The kwan dao is traditionally a heavy spear type polearm. The one on the wall is a lightweight forms competition version. A horse cutter, was exactly what the name implied - a spear like blade with a long handle used to cut down horses in war[image]

Comment: Awesome, can you [edit] your answer to include some links or images of the weapons you describe? I found a wikipedia about guandao but it would be better if you add some references to both.

Comment: Did he have it pre-Julie? Is it foreshadowing of his Sinophilia?