# What book is Rachel reading?

Tags: props, friends

The *Friends* episode "The One with Rachel's Book" has Joey mock Rachel about an erotic novel he found in her room.

But is this just a prop book with the few excerpts Joey reads out being provided by the writers or was this a real book we might be able to pin down?

I've searched for a while now on the internet and I even paused it when Joey finds and reads it, but no luck. The problem is the camera isn't close enough to get a clear image of the title.

Comment: How is this trivia that doesn't add anything to the understanding of the title. The title of the episode is literally The One with Rachel's Book

Comment: @KharoBangdo - This question is along the same lines: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88097/whats-the-weapon-on-rosss-wall. Has nothing to do with the overall plot, but it wasn't closed. The entire plot is about Joey and Ross bothering Rachael about the book, it would have been nice to mention the title.

Comment: These romance novels are a dime a dozen, and it is very likely that instead of using an actual book (and having to deal with all the hassle involving copyrights, etc.) the writers made up their own. That way you can also avoid the necessity of having to source a book that lives up to the reputation it gets in this episode.

Comment: Maybe the just used the advice from Chandler's mom in The One With Mrs Bing: Oh, please, honey, listen, if I can do it, anybody can. You just start with half a dozen European cities, throw in thirty euphemisms for male genitalia, and bam! You have got yourself a book.

Comment: The book is [probably not real](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061118121737AAiUI4U).

Comment: I believe the object of the book is important, not the title or contents. If the contents of the book were important it would probably have been named, so what's important is simply that it's an 'erotic novel'.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.reddit.com/r/howyoudoin/comments/ewmiiv/i_found_rachels_book/

It seems to be "The Vicar's Daughter" by Josi S. Kilpack.

Comment: The book was published in 2017